# Passando informação para uma outra Activity

Tags: android

Bom dia estou tentando passar 2 dados de uma activity para outra mas não estou conseguindo segue abaixo o código relevante na primeira Activity :

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                String phoneNumber="";
                String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String contactId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String hasPhone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                if ( hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                    hasPhone = "true";
                else
                    hasPhone = "false" ;

                if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone))
                {
                    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
                    while (phones.moveToNext())
                    {
                        phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    }
                    phones.close();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString(name, String.valueOf(name));
                    bundle.putString(phoneNumber, String.valueOf(phoneNumber));


                }
                //mainActivity.onBackPressed();
                // Toast.makeText(mainactivity, "go go go", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //    tvname.setText("Name: "+name);
              //  tvphone.setText("Phone: "+phoneNumber);
              //  Log.d("curs", name + " num" + phoneNumber);
            }
            c.close();
        }
        finish();

    }
```

Segue abaixo o código relevante da Segunda Activity :

```
 intent = getIntent();
 Bundle getBundle = null;
 getBundle =  intent.getExtras();
 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
 String name = bundle.getString("name");
 String phone = bundle.getString("phoneNumber");
 messageContact = name+'\n'+ phone;
```

Comment: Diego, alguma resposta resolveu seu problema? Teria algo a mais que possamos explicar?

Comment: @Diego, na verdade, o que voce precisa, pelo que pude ver, e iniciar a activity corretamente, ja que voce coleta os dados no metodo `onActivityResult` e isso so funciona se voce chamar sua segunda activity com `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)` e retornar dela para a primeira activity chamando o metodo `setResult (int resultCode, Intent data)`
aqui tem um bom exemplo: https://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example

Answer (score 1):

Você chama o bundle corretamente, mas falta passar o bundle pelo "Intent".
Segue exemplo (Com bundle):

```
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("id_do_item", "seu_dado");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MinhaOutraActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Para acessar na outra view,use o seguinte codigo:

```
id_user = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id_do_item");
```

Comment: Matheus! mas é o seguinte! eu dou finish em uma activity! se voce reparar eu abro uma activity pra pegar o numero de contato(Agenda do usuário) que o usuário selecionar, logo depois eu finalizo e retorno pra primeira Activity

Comment: É na vdd quando eu postei isso vc n tinha feito a edição ainda.... 
Eu vou Analisar seu código de novo e edito a minha resposta

Comment: certo Matheus, estou no aguardo

Answer (score 0):

#### Erro

O seu erro é estar criando um novo `bundle` e não passá-lo para activy, ou poderia usar o `bundle` do onCreate.

---

#### Como fazer

Há 2 formas:

`Sem o Bundle` (porque seu `intent` já tem um próprio no `onCreate`)

```
public void teste2(View v) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this,Teste.class);
    i.putExtra("site","site2.com");
    startActivity(i);
}
```

`Com` um novo `Bundle`:

```
public void teste(View v) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this,Teste.class);

    Bundle bd = new Bundle();
    bd.putString("site","google.com");

    i.putExtras(bd);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Com novo `bundle`, usando o `putExtras`.

Com o `bundle` do `onCreate`, seria o `putExtra`.

Comment: Raoni! mas é o seguinte! eu dou finish em uma activity! se voce reparar eu abro uma activity pra pegar o numero de contato(Agenda do usuário) que o usuário selecionar, logo depois eu finalizo e retorno pra primeira Activity

Comment: Então você tem tratar na outra activity. Cada activity passa os dados para a próxima.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem

Comment: Por que tu nao chama `startActivity(intent);` apos dar `finish()` na primeira activity?

Comment: Ou salve em algum `sharedpreferences` seus dados entao, e recupere na próxima `activity`

Comment: Toda vez que sai de uma `activity` para outra, precisa passar os dados. Então se você está na `activity 1`, passou os dados para a `activity 2`, e quer voltá-los para a `activity 1`, então também precisa fazer o mesmo processo na `activity 2`. Ou como o LMaker disse, usar `sharedpreferences`, ou outro tipo de `armazenamento` dependendo do que você precisa.

Comment: @LMaker consegui! porém ele está enviando 2 vezes a mensagem para o usuário

Comment: @LMaker se eu chamar pra abrir a activity ele vai dar nullpointer nao?